# Each custom fields needs to have a unique name in this context?

Tags: laravel

I have a form that can have custom fields. The field can be any thing, Whats your email?, Whats your zip code?, etc. Is possible/ok to use the name name for all fields and then in php/laravel store the answers to that questions in the answers table properly? Or each custom field needs to have a unique name?

```
<form method="post" action="">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="custom_field">Whats your email?</label>
        <input type="text" name="custom_field" class="form-control" required="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="custom_field">Receive newsletter?</label>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="radio" name="custom_field[]" value="rad1" class="form-check-input">    
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">rad1</label></div> 
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="radio" name="custom_field[]" value="rad2" class="form-check-input">    
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">rad2</label></div>
        </div>
    </div>  
   <!-- more custom fields -->
<input type="submit" href="#step2" value="Store">
</form>
```

Comment: Try this from laravel validation https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: I think it is ok to use fields with same name